# Jenkins job hangs after big build

Tags: jenkins, openembedded

I build openembedded image with jenkins pipeline. The pipeline ends successfully (according to logs). The finished workspace has about 40 GB. The problem is that even although the pipeline finishes, the job freezes for at least several hours. I am not sure if it ever recovers, as I have always killed it (cannot afford to have jenkins blocked for several days).

I don't observe this when building something small (~ 1GB). I also don't observe it when I wipe out the entire build as the last step. And I don't have any deployment explicitly set up.

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. The problem was caused by cppcheck plugin, which was left activated for all jobs on Jenkins. After disabling the plugin the big jobs end normally.

There was a question about how I figured it out. I realized that there is an active plugin that performs a post-processing on the build output, and that the build output is really, really big. So I tried disabling the plugin and it helped.

Lesson learned: Don't put any post-processing plugins under the `Overview and statistics of all builds` view, as they are activated for all builds, even the undesirable ones.